# How to construct a timber and steel staircase?

Tags: construction, steel, hardwood

I need to produce some detailed staircase technical drawings for unit.

What’s the best way to attach the tread to the riser (*#1/#2/some other way*)?

Also, how do you attach the oak tread to the steel stringer (*#3/some other way*)?

There will also be a sheet of steel running underneath the treads and risers, with an acoustic rubber mat between the steel and oak. Assuming this will simply be glued onto both surfaces?

[image]

Comment: Do you need the riser? It looks better without.

Comment: Risers are typically required by code--keeps folks from slipping through and hurting themselves. What does "for unit" mean?

Answer (score 1):

For connecting tread to stringer, a piece of flat bar welded on to make a bracket (instead of angle).

For risers (if needed) the the top end of the riser is typically held in a groove in the underside of the tread, and bottom end attached to the back of the other tread,

Stringers are often C-section beams (not flat bar).